# Unable to delete users WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have running WSO2 IS 5.0.0 and from time to time I am not able to delete the users. I check into the database and I haven't active tokens, sessions and etc. but I can't remove the users. If I try to delete them though admin console (web page) then the users page just refresh and the user I am trying to delete is still there. If I try to consume Admin Service and perform the delete action everything seems to be fine but the user is still there. What may cause the problem?

This is the stack trace (partial) that I have in the logs after trying to delete the user from admin console:

> [2016-08-02 11:07:16,415] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.listener.IdentityOathEventListener} -  Error while retrieving OAuth application information
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Duplicate entry 'PLCQPGJ8_yYZ9lOb36xFg3gmdVwa-randomUser@carbon.super-AP' for key 'CON_APP_KEY'
>       at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.revokeTokensByResourceOwner(TokenMgtDAO.java:931)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.listener.IdentityOathEventListener.doPreDeleteUser(IdentityOathEventListener.java:92)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.deleteUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:865)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy.deleteUser(UserRealmProxy.java:752)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserAdmin.deleteUser(UserAdmin.java:190)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the backlog? May be you can try installing the SP for IS 5.0 which can be found here : http://wso2.com/more-downloads/identity-server/

Comment: I added few lines of the stack trace so it might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a Bug and as a workaround you can delete entries for that user from IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN table and try deleting the user. Or as I mentioned you can install the SP for Identity Server and try. Or else you can migrate to the latest IS [version](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/).

Steps to reproduce this issue

Steps to reproduce:

```
1.Generate access token 
2. Wait until token expires(VALIDITY_PERIOD)
3. Regenerate token
4.Revoke it.(OAuthAdminService is used)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for to reply. As far as I noticed there an access tokens issued for random_user@yahoo.com and there is a token for random_user@yahoo.com@carbon.super (there are few like the first one, without @carbon.super). Removing the few ones does not lead to removing the user successfully, but deleting all the access tokens which  belong to this particular user does. So I think is something regarding to these tokens. Probably I should investigate more. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vasil, The bug is duplicate entries are being added. It seems this bug is not fixed by the SP as well. You will have to migrate to the latest IS version to get this fixed. Also I have added some steps in the answer for you to reproduce this issue, so it will be easy to debug :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not resolved on `SP`. I hope the `5.1.0` can solve this problem. If you have a custom `jdbc` user store you can modify your `doDeleteUser` cleaning the `IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN` of the record of the user you are deleting before call `super.doDeleteUser()`.

```
@Override
public void doDeleteUser(String userName) throws UserStoreException{ 
  clean_idn_oauth2_access_token(userName);
  super.doDeleteUser(userName);
}
```

I hope this could help you.